# Windows 8 application works on computer but not on windows tablet

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-store-apps, startup, tablet-pc

I am having this weird problem where my Windows 8 application, coded in VB.NET, works perfectly fine on my computer but when I install it on the tablet it does not work.

**Here is what I did in visual studio** : Project -> Windows Store -> Create Application Packages.

**Here is what I did on my tablet** :  I transfered the files created to my tablet where I ran the powershell and installed the application successfully. I then tried to run it but only the white square with an "X" inside of it (default application icon) would shows up and then I am brought back to the start menu.

The application seems to always be running as it is **open in the task bar**. However, it **does not show in the task manager**.

I then tried running the powershell to install my **application on my computer** and it **works perfectly fine**.

To make sure my tablet wasn't the problem I created an **empty application** and it **worked fine on the tablet**

I tried what was proposed here and it still doesn't work : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/all-modern-apps-fail-to-start-after-windows-81/a80793c7-c214-43ec-9ca9-5c758f9ad840

Any ideas to what could be causing this problem ? I can't seem to find a fix to it

This is my windows tablet : Dell Venue 11 Pro (5130)

**Additional information**

There is no code in the form_load event of the main page

There are no error message or exceptions.There is simply a redirect to the start menu as if the application was minimized

Comment: Do you get an exception? You might want to provide more background on what "doesn't work" means in this case.

Comment: There are no exceptions. I am simply brought back to the start page @BrianRasmussen I edited the additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what caused the problem. Probably changes to some configs I did along the way and forgot about

The solution to my specific problem was this :

-Start a new project and include all files from the previous project.

-Create a new service reference.

-Give the permissions to the AppManifest as they were in the previous project

Everything now seems to work perfectly fine on the tablet.

If anyone ever goes through this I would recommand including the previous project piece by piece and testing if it works each time. If there really is a problem with one of the pages/class/etc then you will know which part of the program is causing the problem